# Keycloak next/behind Kong - Pros & Cons

Tags: architecture, keycloak, api-gateway, kong

I'm thinking about a future architecture in micro services and I'm heading to Kong as API Gateway and Keycloak SSO/IAM. 
I wonder how to justify/understand Keycloak's positioning in architecture: behind or next to Kong.
I read the following post:

[Is keycloak behind api gateway a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056708/is-keycloak-behind-api-gateway-a-good-practice/53396041#53396041)

As well as the associated blog that presents Keycloak next to Kong
But I have also identified architectures that offer the authentication manager behind the API Gateway as shown here:

https://blog.octo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/pattern_api_microservices-2.png

Could you help me to better understand the pros and cons so that I can identify which architecture to put in place, please?